# Google Cloud Messaging not working with Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I'm having a lot of trouble to get Google Cloud Messaging to work in my Phonegap-based app.

I'm following the instructions that are [here](http://gielberkers.com/push-notifications-phonegap-android/).
It uses the PushPlugin, which I installed in my app according to the instructions.

Somehow I get no response after registering, nothing happens (no console.log appears) when I do :

```
window.plugins.pushNotification.register(
            pushSuccessHandler,
            pushErrorHandler, {
                "senderID":"12345678", 
                "ecb":"onNotificationGCM"
            }
        );

var pushSuccessHandler = function(result) {
    console.log(result);
};

var pushErrorHandler = function(error) {
    console.log(error);
};

var onNotificationGCM = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    switch(e.event) {
        case 'registered' : {
            console.log('android reg id: ' + e.regid);
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

I setup an API project in Google Developer Console, got a project number that I used as the SenderID, and did all modifications to the Phonegap manifest and config xml files.
My app is not published yet in the Play store.

Is this necessary to get Cloud Messaging working?

And is the code above enough to get a 'reg id', or do I first need to push something from the server, but with what 'reg id' then??

Somewhere I read that the push notifications only work in a Phonegap-app when it is running, or when the notification is clicked, so not when the app is started from the normal icon.  I don't understand this however, because aren't the notifications supposed to work when the app is not running?

Comment: If your app has been "force stopped", your app can not receive push notification. You need to make sure you run your app in a physical device, not emulator.  If there is no console.log printed, that means you have not gotten a reg ID. Reg ID is an ID issued by the GCM servers to the client app that allows it to receive messages. You need to make sure your server is setup correctly, and your app manifest file has correct fields.

Comment: so it should work with just a test app (without publishing) ?  Is there no way at all to verify if it even tries to get a Reg ID ?  Now I don't even know if the request is being sent....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update:***

I'm using Intellij IDEA to build the app. When I compiled with `phonegap build android` the push notifications *were* working ok.

I had to add the '`android-support-v13.jar`' and '`gcm.jar`' files as a library in the Project Settings of the IDEA project, to get it working. These libraries need to be added to the Dependencies of the main module with scope 'Compile'.

Before I only added them directly in Dependencies of the module, with Scope 'Provided' but apparently that doesn't work (although it compiled).

Answer (score 0):

Push notification will work without publishing, publishing is not required.
Only you have to get Sender ID from developer console.
 Sender Id - its project number in developer console

for more detail you can check here

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

I am using it its woreking fine for both android and iOS